# React Native: Make a view take the whole screen when other view is not present

Tags: javascript, react-native, flexbox, react-native-flexbox

This may seem like a basic question, but I can't seem to figure it out or properly word a search on this.
I have a `View` with two other Views in it, one of which sometimes is hidden. So the component looks something like this:

```js
function MyComponent (props) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      {
        props.showButtonView
          ? (
            <View style={{ flex: ??? }}>
              <Button title='do something' onPress={() => console.warn('doSomethign)} />
            </View>
          )
          : null
      }
      <View style={{ flex: ?? }}>
        <Stuff/>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Now, what I am trying to do is have the `Stuff` component cover the entire screen whenever the `Button` is not present. However, if the `props.showButtonView` is true, and we do want to see the view with the `Button` I only want need to see the button on the top, and then the rest is 
whatever is in the `Stuff` component. How do I get this done? Is it based on the flex numbers?

Also, you may be wondering why I need to separate these two into separate Views in the first place, the reason for that is because there are other unrelated things in the `Stuff` component that cover the button and don't allow me to click it. Anyway, long story short, the separation of the two by `View` is mandatory for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> flex should be 1 for both the places.

***Flex:1*** Indicates that it will takes the whole space available after if. So, it doesn't really matters when a button is placed there or not.
 When`props.showButtonView` is **true** then the button is at the top and rest your stuff is placed after that.

Otherwise,

When `props.showButtonView` is **false** then button render code will not be executed and then stuff view will be all over your

Try below code when `props.showButtonView === true`

```
function MyComponent (props) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      {
        props.showButtonView
          ? (
            <View style={{ width: '100%' }}>
              <Button title='do something' onPress={() => console.warn('doSomethign)} />
            </View>
          )
          : null
      }
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Stuff/>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: If I put `flex: 1` on both places, each of their views covers half the screen, which is not what I want since the button is only a fraction of the screen. So on my improvised code, I currently have the button's view with `flex: 1`, which the other one is `flex: 10`, but that doesn't feel right. I want to guarantee that the button will only cover enough space to display the button, while the other view will cover the rest of the screen.

Comment: are you struggling when props.showButtonView is true ?? @theJuls

Comment: Correct. It divides the screen equally. I do not want that since the button is much smaller than the `Stuff` component.

Comment: i have edited the code, please try and accept if it works. Thanks :)

Comment: don't remember the context of this question or anything, but I am sure it worked XD Better 2 years late than never I suppose.